# Prove that two paths on opposing corners of the unit square must cross.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm looking for a simple argument to the following:

Given two (continuous) paths on the unit square, one from (0,0) to (1,1) and the other from (1,0) to (0,1), prove that the paths cross at some point $(x_0, y_0)$.

I have constructed a topological argument for why this is true using compactness (and a proof by contradiction), but the person I'm working with seems to think there is a "simple" and "well-known" argument that says the two paths must cross.  I haven't been able to find such a result.  Does anyone know of one?

Thanks!

Comment: "there exists a single value of t for which the paths cross". Do you mean there is $t\in[0,1]$ such that $\gamma_1(t)=\gamma_2(t)$ ? It is false considering $\gamma_1(t)=(t,t)$ and $\gamma_2(t)=(1-t,0)$ when $0\leqslant t\leqslant 1/2$ et $\gamma_2(t)=(1-t,2t-1)$ for $1/2\leqslant t\leqslant 1$.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that there's a _single_ value of $t$, there can be multiple points where they intersect.

Comment: @Innuo: It's a trivial result by analyzing the function $h(t)=f_1(t)-f_2(t)$ assuming that both paths can be given as graphs of functions. However, there are many paths within the square that are not graphs of functions.

Comment: Oops! That word "single" should not be there, and I've realized from the comments that the parametrization fails.  I've restated the question without the language of parametrization--I had inadvertently used this method this morning when trying to apply the intermediate value theorem and muddied the waters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is Lemma 2 of [this paper](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/jordan/maehara.pdf) by Maehara, which uses the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem.  (I'm not sure if this argument qualifies as "simple" since this theorem is usually proved using homology.)  See also this [MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35514/pair-of-curves-joining-opposite-corners-of-a-square-must-intersect-proof).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an argument using the fundamental group. Suppose there were two such curves $a,b:[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ that didn't meet anywhere, and say $a$ goes from $0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, while $b$ goes from $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$. Consider the map
$$c:[0,1]^2\to S^1,\;(s,t)\mapsto\frac{b(t)-a(s)}{|b(t)-a(s)|}$$
Now consider the restriction $c'$ of this map to the boundary $\partial[0,1]^2\simeq S^1$ which is made of four unit intervals (or paths) $(0,0)\xrightarrow{\;\alpha\;}(1,0)$, $(1,0)\xrightarrow{\;\beta\;}(1,1)$, $(1,1)\xrightarrow{\;\gamma\;}(0,1)$ and $(0,1)\xrightarrow{\;\delta\;}(0,0)$. Then $c\circ\alpha$ goes from $i$ to $-1$ while staying in the upper left quadrant of $\Bbb C\simeq \Bbb R^2$, $c\circ\beta$ goes from $-1$ to $-i$ while staying in the bottom left quadrant, $c\circ\gamma$ goes from $-i$ to $1$ while staying in the bottom right quadrant and $c\circ\delta$ goes from $1$ to $i$ while staying in the top right quadrant. This implies that $c'$ is homotopic to the identity map $S^1\to S^1$, which is a generator of $\pi_1(S^1)\simeq \Bbb Z$, yet by definition, it is also nulhomotopic, having an extension to the square, namely $c$. This yields a contradiction, and so the two paths $a$ and $b$ must meet.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a simple argument. This seems to be equivalent to the Jordan separation theorem, which, although not as difficult as the Jordan curve theorem, is still not exactly elementary.